# How to only get the content of post page while looping?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, id

so I am working with wordpress and I created a calendar with events (custom post_type).
I have a page which shows the calendar with all the event dates from this post_type which works fine.
Now I want at each of this posts from this post_type this calendar to show up again but this time it should only show the event dates of this specific post.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `the_date()` or [`get_the_date( 'd/m/Y', $post->ID )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/) functions. This will show only the date of your post type. If you are outside the loop, you need to use the second function I've suggested with the post id passed as param.